# Implicits from subclass

Tags: scala, implicit, spray

I am trying to implement template method pattern with implicits. Class A is the top class with 2 extensions.

Class A that is defining the template pattern and has some method doSomething(). This method uses several implicits inside. This class is abstract.

Class B and Class C are extending Class A, providing implicits in scope, implementing other abstract methods and are no more abstract.

Example (using spray's pipeline):

```
A:

abstract class A[T <: Any : Manifest] {
    .... 
    abstract def method: PartialFunction[T,Unit] //not interesting

    def doSomething() {
         //method using implicit parser HttpResponse -> T
         val responseFuture: Future[T] = pipeline(Get(url))
         responseFuture.onSuccess(method)
    }
}


B:

import CaseClassB._ //importing implicits that transfer HttpResponse -> CaseClassB
class B extends A[CaseClassB] {
    def method: PartialFunction[CaseClassB,Unit] = {//not interesting}
}
```

This setting does not work (compilation of Class A fails because of "could not find implicit value for evidence parameter"). Is there a better way how to overcome this problem without a need to have something like "implicit abstract def" in Class A that would need to be overriden? The reason I don't like this is that Class B and Class C are providing implicits using imports.

Comment: Ok. Going to provide it :)

Comment: You could require the implicits as implicit parameters to the constructor of `A`, maybe.

Comment: From the sound of the error message, it looks like it's not finding an implicit for `Manifest[CaseClassB]`. But it's hard to tell without the precise error message or the source for `CaseClassB`.

Comment: But I don't think CaseClassB matters, does it? Because I have problem with compilation of class A, regardless of extension class B that will put implicits in. So I think you may assume CaseClassB._ provides implicits that are correct, however compilation will still fail.